# MySQL query: get the next or previous item when list is sorted using value that is not unique

Tags: php, mysql

I have gallery of images. Each image has a rating based on how many users voted "i like this". The MySQL table lokes like this:

```
id       |image      |rating
------------------------------------
166      |6.png      |9
165      |8.png      |9
189      |1.png      |8
171      |99.png     |8
169      |56.png     |8
155      |34.png     |8
265      |7.png      |7
754      |86.png     |6
166      |37.png     |4
342      |95.png     |2
99       |35.png     |0
76       |34.png     |0
44       |3.png      |0
8        |22.png     |0
```

The task is: make it possible to view gallery sorted by rating. It's easy to list images using `ORDER BY rating DESC, id DESC` but problem comes out when user clickes on an image and I must show "Previous image" and "Next Image" buttons next to the opened image.

Suppose we are now looking at image with id=169 from example table:

```
id       |image      |rating
------------------------------------
169      |99.png     |8
```

How can I write my query, to get previous image (id=171)? The problem is, that primary ordering is by `rating` (which is not unique) and secondary is by unique `id`. Which query will give me correct previous image in any situation.

I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE rating >= 8 AND id >=169
ORDER BY rating, id
LIMIT 1
```

but it does not do, because `id >=169` must be checked only if rating is the same.

I'm a bit confused, please help me out.

**UPDATE**

Figured this one on my own. Assuming that I have the `rating` and `id` values for current record, the query to get previous record would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM `images`
WHERE 
    (`rating` = 8 AND `id` > 169)
    OR `rating` > 8
ORDER BY `rating`, `id`
LIMIT 1
```

If `rating = 8 AND id > 169` is not evaluated, then `rating > 8` goes into play. Turned out pretty simple.

Thanks everybody! Accepting the answer with most upvotes.

Comment: I don't understand. Can't you write another query to select the next image, ordered by id?

Comment: @Anzeo nope, he can't. He's images aren't ordered by id, but by rating.

Comment: If you want to get the Previous Record, you need to ORDER BY DESC. This way the `rating` < 8 wont just trigger on the first entry with the lowest Rating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY rating DESC, id LIMIT $n, 1
```

where `$n` is a counter starting at 0. Ordering by id makes sure that subsequent calls always keep the same order. Thus next image would be `$n+1`, previous `$n-1`.

Additionally, you could always fetch 2 images if you want to make sure that there is a next image to the current one (users certainly don't like clicking 'next' to get a 404 error).

EDIT: new requirement from comment

hmm, you could try calculating a minimum distance from you're current image.

```
SELECT * from images
WHERE id < $current[id] AND rating >= $current[rating] 
ORDER by ((abs($current[rating] - rating) << 32) + abs($current[id] - id))
LIMIT 1

SELECT * from images
WHERE id > $current[id] AND rating <= $current[rating]
ORDER by ((abs($current[rating] - rating) << 32) + abs($current[id] - id))
LIMIT 1
```

don't ask me anything about performance though ;)

Comment: I don't really understand where will I get $n? My pages URl is http://example.com/gallery/15?order_by=rating, where 15 is the ID of an image. I can't use "number in sequence" instead of ID because image must have a permanent link. ID of a current image is all I've got.

Comment: Wow, now that cool :) Managed to do this simplier. Take a look at question update.

Comment: @silver you just wasted a great opportunity to "impress" coworkers with an overly complex query ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a cursor oriented approach. The other quite easy method is to select just all IDs via a certain sorting criteria, save those in your application, then browse and select using the IDs and queries specifically selecting the row you want.

Comment: I think a cursor that requires a stored procedure is a bit heavy solution for this problem. The other solution with IDs looks good, but if I have 100K records it will be a performance killer.

Comment: 100k records x 4 bytes (ID) is a killer? 400k raw data hardly seems like a killer to me. Even if you use different sortings (maybe 5 x 100k x 4 bytes), it would still scale pretty well.

Comment: You can also multiply it by 10000 requests per hour :) Anyway, fetching all table contents (even if it is one int column) seems wrong to me, if I only need one record. SQL servers usually are better at this kind of work then PHP is. It seems that the answer is quite simple, I just can't get it. Thank you for your help, I think this solution will work. I'm just hoping for a less "brutal" one :)

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me, I'm not sure. My idea is: Select all IDs in the specific order, save those in your PHP array. Select the record you need via: You currently display the record behind @array[5]. User selects "next", you build the query "select * from images where id = @array[6];". You will only get one record. The query will be cached by the DBMS as it reads (and caches) database blocks instead of single records. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, replace the `test` to your table name and replace the `curr.id =169` to current page id

```
   SELECT curr.id AS currid, curr.image as curr_img, 
           prev.id AS previd, prev.image as prev_img,
           next.id AS nextid, next.image as next_img
    FROM test curr
    LEFT JOIN test prev
       ON prev.id != curr.id
       AND (
          prev.rating > curr.rating
          OR (
                 prev.rating = curr.rating
                 AND prev.id > curr.id
          )
       )
    LEFT JOIN test next
        ON next.id != curr.id
        AND (
           next.rating < curr.rating
           OR (
                  next.rating = curr.rating
                  AND next.id < curr.id
           )
        )
    WHERE curr.id =169
    ORDER BY prev.rating ASC , next.rating DESC , prev.id ASC , next.id DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the entries in one query, put it into a php array, and work with that instead!

Answer (score 0):

I remembered an article I read on the MySQL performance blog about [pagination](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.percona.com%2Fppc2009%2FPPC2009_mysql_pagination.pdf&rct=j&q=PPC2009_mysql_pagination&ei=Wr3STJDZCYm9jAevjriQDg&usg=AFQjCNHTMFrXxeQcOWo7-rSEIq_mMRXy5A&cad=rja) and knocked this example up which might prove helpful (@row_id is redundant)

```
drop table if exists gallery;
create table gallery
(
 id int unsigned not null,
 image varchar(255) not null,
 rating tinyint unsigned default 0
)
engine=innodb;

insert into gallery values
(166,'6.png',9),(165,'8.png',9),(189,'1.png',8),
(171,'99.png',8),(169,'56.png',8),(155,'34.png',8),
(265,'7.png',7),(754,'86.png',6),(37,'37.png',4),
(342,'95.png',2),(99 ,'35.png',0),(76 ,'34.png',0),
(44 ,'3.png',0),(8  ,'22.png',0), (1001 ,'1001.png',0);

drop procedure if exists list_gallery_paged;

delimiter #

create procedure list_gallery_paged
(
in p_last_id int unsigned,
in p_last_rating tinyint unsigned
)
proc_main:begin

    set @row_id = 0;

    if p_last_id <= 0 then
       select @row_id:=@row_id+1 as row_id, g.* 
        from gallery g order by rating desc, id desc limit 4;
    else
      select @row_id:=@row_id+1 as row_id, g2.* 
       from gallery g inner join gallery g2 on g.id = g2.id 
      where
       g.rating <= p_last_rating and (g.id < p_last_id or g.rating < p_last_rating)
      order by 
       g.rating desc, g.id desc limit 4;
    end if;

end proc_main #

delimiter ;

-- in pages of 4 (use all rows)
select g.* from gallery g order by rating desc, id desc;
call list_gallery_paged(0,0);
call list_gallery_paged(171,8);
call list_gallery_paged(754,6);
call list_gallery_paged(99,0);
call list_gallery_paged(8,0);

-- one at a time (use top row only)
select g.* from gallery g order by rating desc, id desc;
call list_gallery_paged(265,7);
call list_gallery_paged(754,6);
call list_gallery_paged(37,4);
call list_gallery_paged(342,2);
call list_gallery_paged(1001,0);
call list_gallery_paged(99,0);
call list_gallery_paged(76,0);
call list_gallery_paged(44,0);
call list_gallery_paged(8,0);
```